# onExit not called in openui5 controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sapui5

I am using tab controller in openui5 where I want to perform some action periodically so I used below code :

```
sap.ui.jsview("oui5mvc.tabs", {
    getControllerName: function() {
        return "oui5mvc.tabs";
    },

    // defines the UI of this View
    createContent: function(oController) {

        var defaultTab = window.sessionStorage.getItem("startDialogue");
        if (null === defaultTab || undefined === defaultTab)
            defaultTab = "home";
        selectedTab = defaultTab.toLowerCase();
        var oTabStrip = new sap.ui.commons.TabStrip("tabStrip", {
            height: ($(window).height() - 40) + "px",
            width: "100%",
            tabs: [
                new sap.ui.commons.Tab(defaultTab.toLowerCase() + "Tab" + tabCount, {
                    text: defaultTab.toUpperCase(),
                    closable: true,
                    selected: true,
                    content: [ // Creating a new tab (e.g.: tab1)
                        new sap.ui.view(defaultTab.toLowerCase() + "view" + tabCount, {
                            viewName: "oui5mvc." + defaultTab.toLowerCase(),
                            type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS
                        })
                    ]
                })
            ],
            close: function(event) {
                var tabidx = event.getParameter("index");
                var tab = oTabStrip.getTabs()[tabidx];
                if (null != tab) {
                    (tab.getContent())[0].destroyContent();
                }
                this.closeTab(tabidx);
                this.removeTab(tabidx);

            },
            select: function(event) {
                var tabidx = event.getParameter("index");
                var tab = oTabStrip.getTabs()[tabidx];
                selectedTab = tab.getText().toLowerCase();
            }
        }).addStyleClass("customTabStrip");
    }
});
```

Below is the code for tab1:

```
var myVar;

sap.ui.controller("oui5mvc.tab1", {

    onInit: function() {
        alert("init");
        //  alert(this.getView());
        //this.getView().setBusy(true); 
    },

    onAfterRendering: function() {

        myVar = setInterval(function() {
            alert("Hello");
        }, 5000);
    },

    onExit: function() {
        clearInterval(myVar);
    },

});
```

But the problem is I am clearing myVar in onExit section openui5 in the tab controller but my problem is my code flow never reaches onExit I wonder why and I want to clear setInterval once tab is closed but the pop still comes even if I close the openui5 tab inside the application. Any tips on how to call onExit while closing tab or any other way to stop the alert after tab is closed.

Comment: Can you show us a demo ? OnTabClose, there is no JS code to be executed..

Comment: I have edited above I want to call clearInterval(myVar); to stop it from executing the alert popup once exited from tab.
As per the scenario I have a tab view js where there are different tabs for different scenarios where in one of the tab I need to use setInterval but that should close once close the tab but that is not happening. Below is the snippet what I do to close the tab in tabs.view.js

Comment: If you are closing your `tab` then there should not be an issue. If you are navigating user to another view then __YES__, you will have to clear the interval. Can you provide the example you are trying with ?

Comment: close: function(event){
var tabidx = event.getParameter("index");
var tab = oTabStrip.getTabs()[tabidx];
if (null != tab){(tab.getContent())[0].destroyContent();
}
this.closeTab(tabidx);
this.removeTab(tabidx);
},

Comment: I have edited the post and mentioned the code that I am trying to execute. Please see above.

Comment: have you tried to use destroy() instead of destroyContent() on your view?

Comment: This does the trick thanks a lot.

Comment: That however calls onExit function but somehow still not able to clear setinterval.

Comment: I would change two more things: first i would reduce myVar to a attribute of the controller. Move it inside the controller definition. Second i would call setInterval in onInit as that is the pendant to onExit. onInit is only called once. onAfterRendering can be called multiple times.

Comment: Doing destroy causes:
It deletes the content of other tabs also in the process of closing the current tab.
Moving setInterval in onInit wont repeat the execution of setInterval every 5secs which is mentioned and is run only once at the time of init.

Comment: One more thing: in your createContent method call `sap.ui.view()` without the `new` keyword. Its not a constructor function. / Your call of `destory()` should only destroy the view in the one tab - unless you add the same view to many tabs. / setInterval runs the given function every five seconds. you have to call setInterval() itself only once.

Comment: setInterval in onInit too do not close the pop up . What actually I want is: 
1. show a busy indicator till the page loads.
2. Update data in the page every 5 minutes.
Is there anyway I can do that without using setInterval. As I need that operation closed while closing the tab.

Comment: And to add that I am using multiple views which are different but tab.view and controller is single which is rendering different views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `setInterval` in your `onInit` method and `clearInterval` in the `onExit` method. `onInit` is called only once to initialize the view. `onAfterRendering` could be called multiple times resulting in multiple intervals registered.

In your `TabStrip.close` event, you have to call `closeTab()` **before** you destroy the tab and its content (the view), otherwise the `TabStrip` has a strange behaviour (probably a bug).
I would recommend to call `destroy()` on the closed tab itself which will also dispose its content (the view).

```
close: function(event){
  var tabidx = event.getParameter("index");
  var tab = this.getTabs()[tabidx];
  this.closeTab(tabidx);
  if (tab!==null){
    tab.destroy();
  }
}
```

For a full example see [here](https://jsbin.com/liruzufuva/edit?html,js,output).

Edit: To show a busy indicator i prefer to call `Control.setBusy(true)` in the `Model.requestSent` event and `Control.setBusy(false)` in the `Model.requestCompleted` and `Model.requestFailed` events. If you start loading your data in the `onInit()` method of your View, it will then show up busy.

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks!